# Prove in a $4 \times 4$ battleship game the expected payoff of player one is $\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: probability, matrices, linear-programming, game-theory

A battleship game is played on a $4 \times 4$ matrix, player one can place their domino(that takes up $2$ adjacent spaces) in one of $24$ places(There are $3$ places in each row and each column it can be placed so $3\cdot 4+3 \cdot 4=24$). Player $1$ secret places the domino and player $2$ secret guesses, which one of the $16$ indexes it's in. If player $2$ guess right they win $1$ dollar and player $1$ loses $1$ dollar. If player $2$ guesses wrong then player $1$ wins $1$ dollar and player $2$ loses $1$ dollar. The expected payoff for player $1$ is $\frac{3}{4}$. Prove this is true.

Reducing this to a 3x4 payoff matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2\\2&2&2\\2&2&2\\2&2&-2\end{bmatrix}$

The above is an example of if player 1 being the row picked a corner then p2 picked the same corner(not entirely sure this is done correctly)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I actually drew out the matrix and drew a pay off matrix, but I think for expected value you normally need the Stochastic vectors representing their mixed strategy cause the expected value is normally $\sum \sum a_{ij}x_iy_j$.

Comment: @Arthur but I guess I don't need the stochastic vectors, because it's supposed to be expected value regardless of what player 2 does, but they never taught us how to calculate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to count the number of arrangements. Two out of $16$ squares are covered, so the probability to hit a covered square is $\frac2{16}=\frac18$. The expected payoff follows directly.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. How does it follow directly? Would you mind explaining? Is it because if player 2 hits with a 1/8 chance there's a payoff of 2? So that's 2/8 average payoff then $1-2/8$=player 1's pay off, which would be 12/16=3/4? I don't think that's right cause it doesn't make sense?

Comment: It's not that simple.  The domino isn't placed randomly so this is actually evaluating a zero-sum game with mixed strategies.  Player $2$ can select a corner, a side, or a central square, yielding various probabilities of winning depending on which strategy Player $1$ selected.  (For example, if Player $1$ selects a corner and Player 2 chooses a side square, then Player $2$ has a probability of $\frac 18$ of winning.)  Player $1$ has $4$ distinct strategies (corner, along side, jutting out from side, central).  I can set up the matrix but I don't remember how to find the Nash equilibrium.

Comment: @RobertShore I think you're definitely on the right track of thinking for how to interpret this problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to calculate the value for player 1, with this. The hint was to use the properties of a payoff matrix, but I haven't found anything that helps.

Comment: @user8714896 Edit your question to insert the payoff matrix you've determined.

Comment: I can't it's too large it's 24x16 and apparently actually working with the explicit matrix is not useful according to the hints

Comment: @user8714896 Use my comment above to reduce it to a $3 \times 4$ matrix.

Comment: I don't see why it's not that simple. Clearly in a Nash equilibrium the first player must ensure that all 16 squares are equally likely to be covered; otherwise the second player's strategy would be to pick one of the more likely squares and thus get a higher payoff (which, since it's a zero-sum game, means a lower payoff for the first player). So we don't need matrices or anything; the first player's expectation is simply $p\cdot(+1)+(1-p)\cdot(-1)=2p-1=\frac34$, where $p=\frac78$ is the probability for the first player to win a dollar if her strategy uniformly covers the squares.

Comment: I think that's it!

Comment: @joriki  It's not obvious to me (without going through the matrix) that it's possible to come up with a mixed strategy for the first player where all squares are equally likely to be covered.

Comment: Player 1 has four strategies:  Corner, Edge, Dangle, Center.  Player 2 has three strategies:  Corner, Edge, Center.  If Player 1 plays Center, then Player 2 has a 50% chance of victory by playing Center, 0 otherwise.  If Player 1 plays Dangle, then Player 2 has a 12.5% chance of victory by playing Edge, a 25% chance of victory by playing Center, 0 otherwise.  If Player 1 plays Edge, Player 2 has a 25% chance of victory by playing Edge, 0 otherwise.  If Player 1 plays Corner, then Player 2 has a 25% chance of victory by playing Corner, 12.5% by playing Edge, 0 otherwise.  That's your matrix.

Comment: @RobertShore: The first player can for instance always place the domino horizontally, adjacent to the left or right margin. There are $8$ such positions, and they form a decomposition of the $16$ squares, so if they are chosen with equal probability, each square is covered with equal probability. (It also "follows" from the given result $\frac34$ that there must be such a strategy, since any strategy that covers the squares unevenly would lead to a higher value for the second player and hence a lower value for the first player.)

Comment: @RobertShore: But you're right that I should have mentioned this, and it's a necessary part of the proof. It doesn't work for odd board sizes; e.g. on a $3\times3$ board, the first player can't achieve a uniform distribution over the squares, and your approach readily solves the game: The second player can achieve a winning probability of $\frac14\gt\frac29$ by playing "Edge", and there's a continuum of Nash equilibria where the first player plays "Corner" with probability $\frac34\le q\le1$ and "Dangle" with probability $1-q$.

Comment: @joriki It follows from your analysis that $50$% Corner, $50$% Dangle should be an optimal strategy for Player 1.